# How to generify multiple methods with common logic applied to different fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, methods

**Marked duplicate question is related to parsing the excel file and usage of the index while this question is related to gentrify common logic for method.**

I have multiple methods which have common business logic applied on the different fields of the DTO. I have around 15 methods that have the same logic applied to different DTO fields, Is there a way to write a generic method that can do the same which accepts the field parameter and format it instead of passing the whole DTO?

```
private void formatDateValue(DTO dto) throws ParseException {
    formatX(dto);
    formatY(dto);
    formatZ(dto);
}

private void formatX(DTO dto) throws ParseException {
    if (dto.getX() != null) {
      if (isBlankOrDash(dto.getX())) {
        dto.setX(null);
      } else {
        dto.setX(getFormattedDate(candidateDTO.getX()));
      }
    }
}

private void formatY(DTO dto) throws ParseException {
    if (dto.getY() != null) {
      if (isBlankOrDash(dto.getY())) {
        dto.setY(null);
      } else {
        dto.setY(getFormattedDate(candidateDTO.getY()));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe we can do it using reflection, but we are not allowed to use it

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice, please.

Comment: Hi @rzwitserloot, Please note that both questions are different, marked duplicate question is related to parsing the excel file and usage of the index while this question is related to gentrify common logic for method.

Comment: I can copy paste the answer for you verbatim. It applies in the exact same fashion. Marking as duplicate seemed more effective.